# Can I use a framework v1.1 gacutil to register a .net v2 assembly?

Tags: gacutil

The server I am working on doesn't seem to have a v2 Gacutil, can I use 1.1 gacutil to register a DLL written for .net v2?

Comment: maybe you can get precise answers on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, gacutil is backword compatible but not forward compatible.  You should be able to get the 2.0 gacutil from the [**.NET 2.0 SDK**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fe6f2099-b7b4-4f47-a244-c96d69c35dec&displaylang=en).